# How do I hook up classes to my Linq-to-Sql?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-sql

Linq / Linq-to-Sql / C# newbie question, but I can't seem to find any useful information on it. It is possible I'm not phrasing the question correctly. Any help appreciated.

So, I have some existing Database tables, and I have generated the DBML file from them. I have the partial classes and the DataContext. How can I connect my Entity classes back to this?

Am I just missing something very obvious?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep your Entity classes separate from your partial DAO classes (which is a good thing for non-trivial applications), the most straightforward way is to create a mapping layer between the two (e.g. `PropertyA` in your DAO class is mapped to `PropertyB` in your Entity class).

If most of the field names/types are identical between the two layers, one way to save a lot of redundant coding is to use a mapping library like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).  It handles identical properties easily and can be configured to handle non-identical properties without too much effort in most cases.

In an MVC project I typically do this in the Repository.  I will have `Map()` functions that take one type of object and create another.  For example, to map a data-layer `Order` class to a domain-layer `Order` class:

```
public Domain.Order GetOrder(int orderID)
{
    Data.Order order = context.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderID = orderID);  // 
    Domain.Order newOrder = Map(order);
    return newOrder;
}

public Domain.Order Map(Data.Order order)
{
    if (!UsingAutomapper)
    {
        // raw way
        Domain.Order newOrder = new Domain.Order
                           {
                               ID         = order.OrderID,
                               Number     = order.OrderNumber,
                               OrderDate  = order.OrderDate
                           };
        return newOrder;
    }
    else  // let AutoMapper do the dirty work
    {
        return Mapper.Map(order);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that makes some sense to me. Do you know where I could find an example of something like this? Thanks.

Comment: Their [wiki](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki) has lots of examples.  You cal also ask _specific_ questions here if you get stuck.

Comment: Not an example of AutoMapper necessarily, but of how to separate the Entity classes but still map them back to the partial classes generated by the DBML.